# Drop-down menu in pine script to choose differents fills background

Tags: input, drop-down-menu, pine-script, fill, tradingview-api

I'm trying to do a simple thing in my mind, but really I don't know the correct syntax or if it's possible with pine script.
I created the following drop-down menu with 4 options using input.string:

```
choose_bg= input.string(title = "Choose background", options = ["RVGI", "MACD", "STOCH", "COLOR"], defval="RVGI")
```

For every option I want to choose a different kind of background fill between two plots, defined as plots, with the conditions I declared. I'll like e.g. if  I choose the first option, the background will fill between two plots, as follow:

```
colors_rvgi= rvgi_value>rvgi_signal ? color.rgb(55, 255, 72, 90) : rvgi_value<rvgi_signal ? color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 90) : na
fill( OBline, OSline , color=colors_rvgi , title="RVGI Background" )
```

Usually I saw that in pine scrip is possible to do the opposite: when the condition is true, then the program apply the option choosen before by the dip-down menu. I want to do the opposite, that it's simple in a boolean input between two condition (false and true).So how can I specify  to pine script the rule "if choose_bg=="RVGI" then fill(as I want)?
thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for choose_bg == "RVGI" for the first field in fill() and return na if false :

```
fill( hline1 = choose_bg == "RVGI" ? OBline : na, hline2 = OSline , color = colors_rvgi , title = "RVGI Background" )
```

Comment: Thank you @G.Lebret, but it gives me error: 'line 50: Cannot call 'operator ?:' with argument 'expr1'='OBline'. An argument of 'plot' type was used but a 'const int' is expected.' I just try to move "random" the conditional ternary operator but always return me errors.

Comment: @fabricab I update my answer, it should work now

Comment: It doesn't, sorry. Mine overbought and oversold lines are seated at first as input, then plotted as a plot, not hline, because I needed to fill them with another plot. Thank you!

Comment: @fabricab simply change hline1 to plot1, you should read the definition of the function : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_fill

Comment: I have read, I tried, but nothing. Anyway I've already defined plot1 as OBline in my code, so I can't give a double definition to a plot...may be better if I paste all code here for better understanding? I don't know, I'm new here as as I'm new with pine script